# awk Find a pattern after a pattern and print its value

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file which has the following format

```
[/Experiment/Run Parameters/Digitizer_0/CAEN_x725_x730_Settings/Channel_1/DPP_PSD_Params]
Short_Gate = WORD : 30
Long_Gate = WORD : 100
Gate_Offset = WORD : 32

[/Experiment/Run Parameters/Digitizer_0/CAEN_x725_x730_Settings/Channel_2/DPP_PSD_Params]
Short_Gate = WORD : 300
Long_Gate = WORD : 1000
Gate_Offset = WORD : 32

[/Experiment/Run Parameters/Digitizer_1/CAEN_x725_x730_Settings/Channel_1/DPP_PSD_Params]
Short_Gate = WORD : 3000
Long_Gate = WORD : 10000
Gate_Offset = WORD : 32

[/Experiment/Run Parameters/Digitizer_1/CAEN_x725_x730_Settings/Channel_2/DPP_PSD_Params]
Short_Gate = WORD : 30000
Long_Gate = WORD : 100000
Gate_Offset = WORD : 32
```

What I'd like to do is get the values from some of these variables (i.e. 30 for Short_Gate, 100 for Long_Gate etc). So the steps should be

1. Find pattern i.e. `[/Experiment/Run Parameters/Digitizer_0/CAEN_x725_x730_Settings/Channel_2/DPP_PSD_Params]`. There are similar patterns like this, with slight differences (i.e. Channel_3 instead of Channel_2 or Digitizer_1 instead of Digitizer_0 etc) throughout the file
2. After that pattern, find the first instance of i.e. `Short_Gate`
3. Give the value that's after `WORD :` or the value of the last field.

I know how to match a pattern in `awk` and print a number of lines after that using for instance

`awk '/Parameters\/Digitizer_0\/CAEN_x725_x730_Settings\/Channel_2\/DPP_PSD_Params/ {print}' file`

but how to find a pattern after a pattern and get the value after `= WORD :` ? I can always use `-F ":"` and print the second column but the format of the file can be changed. Also there are multiple entries in the file that start with `Short_Gate`, `Long_Gate` etc

The expected output should look like this

`30`

when `[/Experiment/Run Parameters/Digitizer_0/CAEN_x725_x730_Settings/Channel_1/DPP_PSD_Params]` and `Short_Gate` is requested,

`100`

when`[/Experiment/Run Parameters/Digitizer_0/CAEN_x725_x730_Settings/Channel_1/DPP_PSD_Params]` and `Long_Gate` is requested etc.

Comment: Could you please do mention expected output in your question and let us know then.

Comment: Are there multiple lines starting with `Short_Gate`?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: Thanks for your comment! I updated my question!

Comment: @anubhava: Thanks a lot for your comment! Yes, there are multiple lines starting with `Short_Gate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following, based on OP's latest edited expected output.

```
awk -v var="/Experiment/Run Parameters/Digitizer_0/CAEN_x725_x730_Settings/Channel_1/DPP_PSD_Params" '
/^\[/{
  found=""
}
$0=="[" var "]"{
  found=1
}
found && /Short_Gate/ && match($0,/WORD : [0-9]+/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  gsub(/[^0-9]+/,"",val)
  print val
  val=""
}' Input_file
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! I edited my question to give more info!

Comment: @Thanos, sure, could you please check my edited answer now and lemme know if this helps you?

Comment: Thanks a lot! What this does is to print practically everything in the file that follows `WORD : `. What I need to do is to find pattern `/Experiment/Run Parameters/Digitizer_0/CAEN_x725_x730_Settings/Channel_2/DPP_PSD_Params`, then find `Short_Gate` and print the value after `WORD : ` or similarly the last field.

Comment: @Thanos, ok I have added EDIT solution  kindly check and lemme know then?

Comment: Thanks again! The new command prints everything that has `Short_Gate` in the file. Maybe I'm not clear enough in my question. I'll edit it again.

Comment: @Thanos, so after your `experimental` line you don't want to print all `Short`_Gate` lines?

Comment: Exactly! I want only the first that appears after the `experimental` line. Check my edited question. I think I made it more clear. Apologies for that :/

Comment: @Thanos, could you please try now and lemme know?

Comment: It is indeed working! Thanks you so much for your help!!

Comment: I have a quick question: I tried to run your command in an one liner using `awk -v var="/Experiment/Run Parameters/Digitizer_0/CAEN_x725_x730_Settings/Channel_4/DPP_PSD_Params" '/^\[/{found=""}$0=="[" var "]"{found=1} found && /Long_Gate/ && match($0,/WORD : [0-9]+/){ val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) gsub(/[^0-9]+/,"",val) print val val="" }' file` but I get a ` ^ syntax error` pointing to `print`. Any idea?

Comment: @Thanos you can separate awk statements with newlines or semicolons. You can't just remove one without replacing it with the other.

Comment: @Thanos, since you are requesting for a one-liner here it is `awk -v var="/Experiment/Run Parameters/Digitizer_0/CAEN_x725_x730_Settings/Channel_1/DPP_PSD_Params" '/^\[/{found=""} $0=="[" var "]"{found=1} found && /Short_Gate/ && match($0,/WORD : [0-9]+/){val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);gsub(/[^0-9]+/,"",val) ;print val;val=""}' Input_file` lemme know please in case of any queries.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: It's working like a charm! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk -F ' *: *' '/^\[/ {
   p = (index($0, "/Experiment/Run Parameters/Digitizer_0/CAEN_x725_x730_Settings/Channel_2/DPP_PSD_Params") > 0)
}
p && NF==2 {
   print $2
}' file
```

```
30
100
32
2162753
8711
261
65535
0
0
0
2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -v hdr='[/Experiment/Run Parameters/Digitizer_0/CAEN_x725_x730_Settings/Channel_2/DPP_PSD_Params]' \
      -v fld='Short_Gate' '
    !NF { f=0 }
    f && ($1 == fld) { print $NF }
    $0 == hdr { f=1 }
' file
300
```